# How to deploy just the code in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-client

In my work, i've to update a certain part of a project, that's its made in Next.js and deployed in Google Cloud Platform, i have done my work successfully but now i don't now how to trigger a re-deploy on GCP because the code doesn't have a `app.yaml` or a CI/CD implementation, and I don't know how the code was uploaded to GCP without either of these two ways

So I was wondering if there is a way to update the code, without deploying the GCP client with the `app.yaml` file and CI/CD. To upload the code, since I will not have to make any more changes

Comment: You need to know which part of GCP you're using since that will affect how you deploy. Since you say you don't have an ```app.yaml```, that most likely means you're not using GAE. Do you have a docker file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just running the script using npm run start /  node index.js / python3 main.py etc.
If you are really using Google Cloud Platform and its servers, you would need a configuration file -  app.yaml file/Dockerfile/ cloudbuild.yaml

For App Engine, you must first create the app.yaml file for the default service of your app before you can create and deploy app.yaml files for additional services.
To deploy your application's service, run the following command from the directory where the app.yaml file of your service is located:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

By default, the gcloud app deploy command deploys only the app.yaml file in your current directory. Whenever you run this command, App Engine generates a unique ID for the version that you deploy, deploys the version to the Cloud project you configured the gcloud CLI to use, and routes all traffic to the new version. The new version becomes the default version.

If you are using Cloud Build for the deployment, build your Docker image using a build config file: use a Cloudbuild.yaml file/cloudbuild.json file

For a pre-built Docker image:

1. In the same directory that contains your application source code,
   create a file named cloudbuild.yaml or cloudbuild.json.
2. In the build config file:

> Add a name field and specify the pre-built Docker image. The
> pre-built image is stored in the Container Registry at
> gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker. In the example config file below, the
> name field specifies that the pre-build Docker image is used by Cloud
> Build to execute the task indicated by the args field.

3. Start the build using the build config file:

> gcloud builds submit --region=REGION --config CONFIG_FILE_PATH
> SOURCE_DIRECTORY

To build Docker image:

Cloud Build allows you to build a Docker image using just a Dockerfile. You don't require a separate build config file. To build using a Dockerfile, run the following command from the directory containing your source code and the Dockerfile:

```
gcloud builds submit --region=REGION --tag gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE_NAME
```

So if you are not doing the above, I would like to know how you are deploying the app without config files.
And coming to your question, yes you can redeploy the app, by :

1. Just running the same command you used to originally deploy the app:
   $ `gcloud app deploy` This will replace the currently running
   instances with the new app. Add `--no-promote` if you want to deploy
   without routing service to the latest version deployed.
2. [Creating  a Cloud Build trigger](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers) which automatically starts a build
   whenever you make any changes to your source code. You can configure
   the trigger to build your code on any changes to the source
   repository or only changes that match certain criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve your `app.yaml` configuration file from the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions?project=%3Cproject-id%3E), Click on the `View` under `Config` from the App Engine -> Versions.

[image]